# Não consigo encontrar o erro dessa Stored procedure

Tags: mysqli, mysql

```
delimiter $$
create procedure reposta(out mensagem varchar(100))
begin
  if new.codigo_veiculo != null then
  set mensagem = "Algum veículo está sendo utilizado";
end $$
delimiter ;
```

erro que aparece

> Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: faltou o `end if;` após ter setado o valor em `mensagem`

Comment: funcionou obrigado....

Answer (score 0):

Correção:

Para todo `IF` é necessário inclusão de um `END IF;` conforme abaixo:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure reposta(out mensagem varchar(100))
begin
  if (new.codigo_veiculo != null) then
     set mensagem = "Algum veículo está sendo utilizado";
  end if;
end $$
delimiter ;
```